# hue connect hive had an error

Tags: hive, hadoop2, hue

```
Failed to open new session: java.lang.RuntimeException:
 org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(org.apache.hadoop.security.authorize.AuthorizationException): 
User: hadoop is not allowed to impersonate cheng
```

User:hadoop is my hadoop install use,and cheng is ubuntu user.

I have already the following configuration in my `core-site.xml`:

```
<name>hadoop.proxyuser.hive.hosts</name>
    <value>*</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>hadoop.proxyuser.hive.groups</name>
   <value>*</value>
</property>
```

Answer (score 0):

the hive user is not exist before,so I change the hadoop.proxyuser.hive.groups to
hadoop.proxyuser.hadoop.group and so on.in hue config hue.ini,set the hue user.
so the problem is solution.